# How to query in SQL Server with databasename.owner.tablename using oracle dg4odbc

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle11g, dblink

I have a working dg4odbc connection from Oracle 11g to SQL Server 2005. Oracle connects to SQL Server using unixODBC with FreeTDS. I can do simple query like:

```
select count(*) 
from tablename@sqlserver_dblink
```

but what I want to do is

```
select count(*) 
from databasename.owner.tablename@sqlserver_dblink
```

to another database in same SQL Server.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The database name and owner (concepts are different in SQL SErver) are part of the ODBC connection DSN.  They are not specified in your SQL.  The database link (@sqlserve_dblink) is an object within your oracle db. The db link definition has a property called HOST, which specified an entry in the database's tnsnames.ora file.  That, in turn resolves to a destination where your oracle gateway has a listener.  From there it gets resolved to a gateway configuration file that in turn specifies the ODBC driver and DSN.  The DSN is what specifies the actual SQL Server database and credentials.